# How to commit project to new repository? Git Hub

Tags: git

I recently deleted my Git Hub account and created a new one,but when I try to commit projects to the new account, I'm getting errors referring to projects from the old account like:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/BrianVarley/College-Final-Year.git/' not found
```

Though the repo I'm commiting to is not that name. The command sequence I'm using is as follows:

```
cd F:\Projects\AndroidBrian
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

After the previous statement I get this error also:

> nothing added to commit but untracked files present

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/BrianJVarley/2nd_Year_Android.git
git push -u origin master
```

The new account is also BrianJVarley and repo name is 2nd_Year_Android

Is there a way to fix this? Why do you think its still using my old account and projects?

Comment: Your "command sequence" doesn't commit anything. So there nothing to push. Check it with `git log`

Comment: Does the project name on my machine have to match the repo name on git hub??

Comment: there is no such a thing like a "project name" for git. If what you're referring to is a directory name - then no, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, change the path to the correct one in a `.git/config` file

> Why do you think its still using my old account and projects?

Because you haven't changed it manually and `git` cannot read your minds

Comment: I edited my question to explain further.Also how do I change the path  in the `.git/config` file? I opened it and it contains the correct username and email as I set this up when I reinstalled.

Comment: @Brian J: if it does - it will `push` to the correct repository.

Comment: Ok Ill give that a goo now.

Comment: Now I init after cd to project directory then gid add .  shows error `fatal: Not a git repository: AppData/Local/GitHub/PoshGit`

Comment: @Brian J: if `git` states it's not a repository - I don't see a reason to not believe it

Comment: fair enough,I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong here,the project name is the same in the directory on my flash drive as the directory I use when I init. From what I understand when I cd to the directory and  call init,the local repo for my project has been created?

Comment: @Brian J: yep. `git init` creates a repository in the current directory

Comment: so why is it when I create the local repo and then call add . it gives me the `not a git repo` error? What exactly am I doing wrong here? This exact same set of commands worked before when I had my old account..

Comment: @Brian J: I have no idea what commands you have run. The commands from the question run as expected